# I made a python download sorter but there's a little error called [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''

Tags: python, sorting

The Problem is there's an error when i run the script called
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pWux.png)

[terminal log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWg9A.png)
here's the script:

```
import os

# Get a list of all the files in the current directory
files = os.listdir('.')

# Sort according to extention
files.sort(key=lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])

# for loop to itrate thru list
for file in files:
  # base name and extention split eg. joe .mama (folder: mama; folder chya andar: joe)
  name, extension = os.path.splitext(file)

  #pahale directory banwachi, if dosent exist
  directory = extension[1:]
  if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
  

  # Move the file into the directory for its file extension
  os.rename(file, f'{directory}/{file}')
```

any help will be appreciated thanks : ) <3

the script was working fine when i ran it for the fist time but when i ran it for second time there's this error

Comment: `extension` will be a blank string for filenames that do not have an extension, and this causes the error when you try to call `os.makedirs()` on a blank string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't handling files with no extension, add some handling for that.  for example;

```
import os

# Get a list of all the files in the current directory
files = os.listdir('.')

# Sort according to extention
files.sort(key=lambda x: x.split('.')[-1])

# for loop to itrate thru list
for file in files:
  # base name and extention split eg. joe .mama (folder: mama; folder chya andar: joe)
  name, extension = os.path.splitext(file)

  #pahale directory banwachi, if dosent exist
  directory = extension[1:] if extension[1:] != '' else 'None'
  if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
  

  # Move the file into the directory for its file extension
  os.rename(file, f'{directory}/{file}')
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a better version of the code I wrote

```
import os
import shutil

# Sort and move files according to their extension

# Get a list of all the files in the current directory
files = os.listdir('.')

# Sort the files by extension
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[1])

# Iterate through the files
for file in files:
  # Split the file name and extension
  name, extension = os.path.splitext(file)

  # Create the destination directory for the file
  if extension != '':
      directory = extension[1:]
      if not os.path.exists(directory):
          os.makedirs(directory)
  else:
      directory = 'None'

  # Move the file to the destination directory
  shutil.move(file, os.path.join(directory, file))
```

thanks for the help : )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).